# Why is id property added only to subsequent objects of Memory store?

Tags: dojo

When leaving out the idProperty on creation of the object store, why do subsequent objects that are added to a memory store, get an id property, but the objects that were used in the creation of the memory store do not?

For example

```
var employees = [{
    name: "Krishna",
    topic: "Sales"
}, {
    name: "Mohhamad",
    topic: "Sales"
}];

var employeeStore = new Memory({
    data: employees,

});

employeeStore.add({ name: "Joe", topic: "Marketing" });
```

My data contains the following objects

```
{
    name: "Krishna",
    topic: "Sales"
},
{
    name: "Mohhamad",
    topic: "Sales"
},
{
    id: 0.8244685191447396,
    name: "Joe",
    topic: "Marketing"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `dojo/store/Memory.js` you'll notice that `setData` (the method initially executed to put original data in the store) does not rely on the `put` method of the store.
It simply loop over the given object and create the index, expecting the `idProperty` to be there.
If you case, because you do not provide the `idProperty`, I assume the index get totally screwed. All indexes will be mapped to `undefined` (see line 159 of `dojo/store/Memory.js`).

However, the `put` method is adding the a value to the `idProperty` if it is missing. That is what you describe in your question.

As a workaround you can:

- be sure there is an id for each objects you give to `setData`
- call `setData` with empty array, then loop over your initial objects and use `put` for all of them